# Transfer a list of programs to another PC

Tags: windows, installer, serialization

I'm looking for software that can install all my previous programs from one pc to another, with the same windows OS (7 and onwards).

I don't want an image, I'm only looking for a program that can do the reinstallation, in a quick and efficient manner.

The closest would be `dpkg` on Linux that can reinstall all the libraries from one Linux machine to another, if the OS version is the same.

Here, it would not be a library reinstall, it would be programs.

Comment: If you want to do it manually, copy the program directories to the ***idenitcal*** path on the new PC., then start `regedit` and export the `SOFTWARE` hive of `HK_CURRENT_USER` and `HK_LOCAL_MACHINE`

Comment: Hi @Mawg would it be the only way? I want something that can serialize that, but in a kind of `clean` or as clean as possible, manner

Comment: I don't know of any tool, so that is all that I can think of. I hope that someone recommends a tool to you

Comment: @Mawg: that's a really critical operation. Did you try that yourself before giving this advice? The Registry contains system/hardware specific stuff.

Comment: @Mawg: some software also installs into .NET GAC or System32 directory. I really doubt that your approach works.

Comment: Thomas, to your first point, I specifically stated the `SOFTWARE` hive, so no need to worry about drivers or other hardware related stuff. Yup, I did try this, and it did work. However, you have a valid point in your second comment. I forgot to mention coping the DLL directories. Personally, I have done this often, and tend to reinstall Windows every few months, so do not install programs in my C: partition. I also use portable versions where possible. A little late for the OP, I know, but good advice for next time

Comment: Hey @Mawg whilst (re)installing `cmder`, I did realize it was a portable app hence my answer. Anyway, thanks for your input. I definitely think that chocolatey's serialization capabilities is definitely what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and I went for [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/). While it does not provide the feature to install everything what you already had, I did it this way:

- On the old machine (must be running)

  - Use [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner)
  - Go to Tools, Uninstall
  - Save as text file
  - Copy the file
- On the new machine

  - [Search](https://chocolatey.org/packages?q=) for Chocolatey packages
  - create a batch file with all `choco install xyz` commands. Mine has ~80 lines now.

Hopefully, next time I do not need to go through this process any more but I can use the batch file directly.

Downsides of this approach:

- Not all applications are available. I mainly miss some commercial applications.
- It turned out that [Chocolatey Skype was unable to update](https://superuser.com/questions/1147775/skype-update-cannot-find-file), but that may be a temporary issue.
- Some packages are broken due to recent changes which require a checksum. Such a checksum is basically a good idea, but broken packages are annoying.
- Your configuration and data is not configured. E.g. Putty and WinSCP store their settings in the Registry, which [required extra tools](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/37653/registry-viewer-for-ntuser-dat-files)

Comment: blimey! @thomas-weller! simply awesome!!

Answer (score 1):

I did not find the software that would do what I was wishing.

However, I found two things, which are decent workaround

- [Portable app](http://portableapps.com): It gives a list of apps, which do not need installs
- This [link](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-create-portable-app/) teaches you how to create portable apps

Comment: After two days, you can accept this as the answer, if you think that it will help others in future